# When I run the yarn hardhat test the console only shows 0passing(0ms) and the test didn't run

Tags: solidity, ether, hardhat-deploy, test, chai

When I run the `yarn hardhat test` the console only shows 0passing(0ms), which means the test didn't run.

```
const { assert, expect } = require("chai")
const { ethers, deployments, getNamedAccounts } = require("hardhat")

describe("FundMe", async function () {
  let fundMe
  let deployer
  let MockV3Aggregator
  const sendValue = ethers.utils.praseUnits("1", "gwei")

beforeEach(async function () {
    //using hardhat deploy our contract
    deployer = (await getNamedAccounts()).deployer
    // const accounts = ethers.getSigners()// return accounts in the networks
    //deployments.fixture(["all"]) can run js with all tags under the deploy direction in the localhost
    await deployments.fixture(["all"])
    // return the lastest deployed contract which connected with deployer
    fundMe = await await ethers.getContract("FundMe", deployer)

    // fundMe = await deployments.get("FundMe", { from: deployer })
    MockV3Aggregator = await ethers.getContract(
        "MockV3Aggregator",
        deployer,
    )
})

describe("constructor", async function () {
    it("set the aggreator address correctly", async () => {
        const response = await fundMe.getPriceFeed()
        assert.equal(response, MockV3Aggregator.target)
    })
})

describe("fund", async function () {
    it("Fails if you don't send enough ETH", async () => {
        await expect(fundMe.fund()).to.be.revertedWith(
            "You need to spend more ETH!",
        )
    })
    it("update", async function () {
        await fundMe.fund({ value: sendValue })
        const response = await fundMe.s_addressToAmountFunded(deployer)
        assert.equal(response.toString(), sendValue.toString())
    })
})
})
```

Comment: Try running it with exact path once. `yarn hardhat test ./test/YourTestFile`

Comment: in the end,i find the question.Due to i use this code` const sendValue = ethers.utils.praseUnits("1", "gwei")`, but i don`t import the sol code